# Hermite Polynomials: Rodrigues to Integral Representation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, complex-integration

I would like to go from this representation of the Hermite polynomials:

$$H_n(z)=(-1)^ne^{z^2}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}e^{-z^2} \tag{1}$$

to this representation

$$H_n(z)=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(z+is)^n\,e^{-s^2}\,ds \tag{2}$$

I have tried to use Cauchy's theorem to give the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ derivative term in terms of a contour integral, and then contort the integrand and contour so that we're left with an integral over the real line, but I just can't find a way to do it. I've also read [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/integral-representations-of-hermite-polynomial), but all of answers go through a different representation/route than the one I desire. Could you help me out?

**EDIT:** To shed some light on what exactly I desire, I will present the first few steps of my attempted path. For an analytic function $f(z)$, we can express its $n^{\textrm{th}}$ derivative by a contour integral.

$$\frac{d^n}{dz^n}f(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}} dw $$

Where $\Gamma$ is a simple closed curve that encircles the point $z$ in the complex plane. Using this we can rewrite $(1)$ as

$$H_n(z)=(-1)^ne^{z^2}\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} \frac{e^{-w^2}}{(w-z)^{n+1}} dw$$

**I don't know where to go from here.** If I make the substitution $s=w-z$, I end up going in a circle showing that $H_n(z)=H_n(z)$. Moreover, I can't find a simple way to reduce that integral to an integral over $\mathbb{R}$ (due to the gaussian term in the integral).

Comment: @ Arturo don Juan, Is what you have an idea for regarding the next question :    ([Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086044/complex-hermite-polynomials-as-an-eigenfunction-of-an-operator)) ? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that we can write $e^{-z^2}$ as the integral

$$e^{-z^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-s(s+2iz)}\,ds \tag 1$$

Taking the $n$'th derivative of $(1)$ with respect to $z$ yields

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(e^{-z^2}\right)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (i2s)^n\,e^{-s(s+2iz)}\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-z^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-is)^n\,e^{-(s+iz)^2}\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-z^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (-i(s-iz))^n\,e^{-s^2}\,ds\\\\
&=\frac{(-1)^n\,2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-z^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (z+is)^n\,e^{-s^2}\,ds\tag 2
\end{align}$$

Multiplying both sides of $(2)$ by $(-1)^n\,e^{z^2}$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
H_n(z)&=(-1)^n\,e^{z^2}\,\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\left(e^{-z^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\,2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (z+is)^n\,e^{-s^2}\,ds
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Although I am not sure exactly what you are seeking, I wanted to present a way to show that the integral expression in the OP is indeed the $n$'th order Hermite Polynomial.

Proceeding, we use the binomial theorem to write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (z+is)^n e^{-s^2}\,ds&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}i^kz^{n-k}\int_{-\infty}^\infty s^ke^{-s^2}\,ds \\\\
&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}i^kz^{n-k}\left(\frac{1-(-1)^k}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2}\right) \\\\
&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}(-1)^kz^{n-2k}\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right) \\\\
&=\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}(-1)^kz^{n-2k}\left(\sqrt{\pi}\,\frac{(2k)!}{4^k\,k!}\right) \\\\
&=2^nn!z^n\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2z}\right)^{2k}\frac{1}{k!(n-2k)!} \tag 3
\end{align}$$

where $(3)$ is the explicit expression for the $n$'th order [Hermite Polynomial found here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Explicit_expression).

Comment: I would say that it is very clear that OP wants to go from the representation in the first formula to the representation in the second formula (and not via some other representation).

Comment: Thank you @Dr.MV, but this isn't too different from the answers for the question I linked. See my edit.

Comment: @Dr.MV Wow! Where did that first integral representation of $e^{-z^2}$ come from?

Comment: @Dr.MV Okay, I figured it out. That first step is made with quite the malice aforethought!

Comment: Arturo, thanks for the votes!!  Much appreciated.  The inspiration is akin to "[Feynman's Trick](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/inactive-objects/use-feynmans-trick-for-evaluating-integrals.html)."  We want a term that is an integral, like $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax}\,dx$, for which upon taking $n$ successive derivatives yields $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}a^ne^{ax}\,dx$.  We also want the value of the integral to represent $e^{-z^2}$.  Then, it is a matter of trial and error to find the form of the integral used in the development.  - Mark

Comment: Nice answer (as always) and a well deserved (+1)

Comment: @tired Thank you (as always).  I really appreciate it!!  - Mark

Comment: Any help are welcome  for regarding the next question :    ([Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086044/complex-hermite-polynomials-as-an-eigenfunction-of-an-operator)) ? Thank you in advance