# Complex hermite polynomials as an eigenfunction of an operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, special-functions, spectral-theory, harmonic-analysis, orthogonal-polynomials

The real Hermite polynomials are given by
$$H_n(x)=(-1)^n e^{x^2}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{-x^2}$$ 
for $x\in \mathbb R$ and $n=0, 1, 2 ...$. The Hermite function $H_n$ of order $n$ is an eigenfunction of the harmonic oscillator $\Delta=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+x^2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2n+1$, i.e., $$\Delta H_n (x)=(2n+1)  H_n(x) .$$

I would like to know, what happens for the complex  Hermite polynomials given by
$$H_n(z)=(-1)^n e^{z^2}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}e^{-z^2}$$ 
for $z\in \mathbb C$ and $n=0, 1, 2 ...$, i.e. it exists an operator $\Delta_z$ such that , i.e., $\Delta H_n (z)=\lambda_n \, H_n(z) ?$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Recheck the exponents in $H_n$. Your $H_n$ is a polynomial, but the Hermite functions are not because $\sim e^{-x^2/2}$. That said, the solutions you have for the real equation automatically extend to the complex via the identity principle. Replace $x$ by $z$ and real derivatives by complex ones, and the resulting equation still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference - i.e. the Hermite polynomials are trivially (and uniquely!) extended to the rest of the complex plane via analytic continuation. It's really that simple, though it may be understandably non-intuitive.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials