# Integrating Hermite Polynomials of Trigonometric Functions

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, special-functions, contour-integration, hermite-polynomials

I'm interested in the integral

$$ \int_0^{2 \pi} dx \ H_\ell (\cos x) H_m (\sin x) e^{ i n x} = 0 $$

I tried expressing the polynomials as contour integrals but got stuck. Maybe one can obtain some recursion relation?

Even if we can't do the integral, how would you prove that it vanishes if $n > \ell +m$?

Comment: Can you try to be more specific about what you tried? How did you attempt to express the Hermite polynomials as contour integrals?

Comment: I used the formulas given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18325/integral-representations-of-hermite-polynomial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple with contour integration - in fact, barely any calculation at all.  Rewrite the integral as

$$-i \oint_{|z|=1} dz \, H_{\ell} \left (\frac{z+z^{-1}}{2} \right ) \, H_{m} \left (\frac{z-z^{-1}}{i 2} \right ) z^{n-1}$$

The Hermite $H_{\ell}$ has maximum degree $\ell$, so the highest-order term in $z^{-1}$ is $z^{-\ell}$,  and similarly for $H_m$ is $z^{-m}$.  Thus, is $n \gt \ell+m$ then the integrand is a polynomial and the integral is therefore zero by Cauchy's theorem.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you know if the integral can be done in closed form?

Comment: @Jessica: it should be doable to evaluate in closed form.